# Ionic trouble: can't build to android

Tags: windows, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I've got an Ionic 3.4 project and trying to build it to Android for testing purposes.

I installed Android Studio and the Android SDK, aswell Java 8. Then did:

> ionic cordova platform add android

Then, when I write...

> ionic build android

... I get the following error:

> > cordova build android ✖ Running command - failed!
>
> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit
>   code 1):
>
> ```
>     ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Zerok\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>     JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121
>     Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
>     or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
>     in your path, or install Android Studio
> ```

What's going on? I also installed Gradle 4.0 into the Java folder, and pointed towards it in the GRADLE_HOME environment variable:

```
Var name: GRADLE_HOME
Value: C:\Program Files\Java\gradle-4.0
```

Also added the following to the path:

```
GRADLE_HOME\bin
```

But it still throws the same error... I don't think it's a problem with plugins, but with the Ionic/Cordova build system. What I don't understand, is why it needs Gradle when it's perfectly working in Android Studio, maybe it's because it's not in C:/, but a different disk? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already fixed it. And the fix is weird as hell, but well, at least it works.

Solution: uninstall Android Studio and install it in the main drive (C in my case). Everything began to work perfectly after this clean install.

Comment: Dude, friendly advice: Don't use Windows for development... And if you do, don't change default installation paths. I'm happy you could fix it though.

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer and upvote for later readers. Thanks.

Comment: @maninak You're right, but I'm a frequent windows user and I feel comfy with it, that's why I keep using it and only use Linux for my servers. And yes, will mark this answer when I can!

Answer (score 1):

*(Assuming Windows 10)*

1. open Start Menu, type `path` and hit `Enter`
2. `System Properties` will open. On the bottom click `Environment Variables...`
3. In the window that opens, on the bottom section named `System Variables`, double click `Path`
4. Click `New` and copy paste the path to your gradle installation

Make sure the `path` environment variable points to the `bin` folder of gradle like so: `export PATH="$PATH:/home/jeffbl/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bi‌​n"`.

If that doesn't work try:

```
$ cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android && cordova build
```

If that doesn't work then use the SDK manager to downgrade to an earlier version of your SDK. It might be that there is no graddle wrapper out yet for the latest.

In any case you will find the answer to your problem in [this github issue](http://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10604).

Comment: Thank you! But that didn't help at all. Tried to put the system environment variable in PATH directly, just putting in the Gradle bin folder as value. But the error keeps being the same.

Comment: >ionic cordova requirements
[ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova requirements
it doesn't find that command... also, Android Studio is installed, two SDK's are installed and the Gradle plugin was already in...

Comment: Make sure the path env var points to the bin folder of gradle like so `export PATH="$PATH:/home/jeffbl/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin"`. If that doesn't work try `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android && cordova build`. If that doesn't work then use the SDK manager to downgrade to an earlier version of your SDK. In any case you will find the answer to your problem over here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10604